# What are all the gender/racial perks?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

According to [this post](http://forums.bethsoft.com/index.php?/topic/1286166-hidden-stat-differences-based-on-race-selection/page__st__20), your race and gender create a ratio that affects melee damage, run speed, and jump height.

Aside from listed racial abilities and starting skills, is anything else in the game affected by your race/gender combo?

For reference, the linked chart:

```
Argonian Male: 1.01          Argonian Female: 1.00
Breton Male:   1.00          Breton Female:   0.95
Dark Elf Male: 1.00          Dark Elf Female: 1.00
High Elf Male: 1.08          High Elf Female: 1.08
Imperial Male: 1.00          Imperial Female: 1.00
Khajiit Male:  1.00          Khajiit Female:  0.95
Nord Male:     1.03          Nord Female:     1.03
Orc Male:      1.04          Orc Female:      1.04
Redguard Male: 1.00          Redguard Female: 1.00
Wood Elf Male: 0.98          Wood Elf Female: 1.00
```

**Edit:**
It seems race/gender also affect a [character's weight](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Races), but it's unknown what effect weight has on the game.

Comment: See http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3176/hidden-pages-of-gaming for discussion about questions like this.  It would be very interesting to have a question of "Do different races do different damage" with that chart linked in the answer.  But asking about for a list of other mysterious differences isn't an effective question.

Comment: Suddenly, the Thalmor elitism makes sense.

Comment: setting your own scale to 5 and then running across Skyrim is very entertaining, not to mention the fact that now the 'giants' only reach up to the top of your boots

Comment: The 9th post on the third page of the link you provided shows evidence that the base scale of your character does *not* affect melee damage.

Comment: My question, "[Characters have different weights depending on their race and sex. How does the weight (not Carry Weight/encumbrance) of a character affect the game?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/55027)" has been closed as an exact duplicate of this question. Could OP also specify that characters (both player and NPC) have [different weights depending on their race and sex](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Races), and ask how does the weight of a character affect them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At this time, there are no other known differences (other than cosmetic things like how people address you).  Of course, a week ago we didn't know about the scaling differences either.  But until someone proves me wrong, nothing else is different.

Comment: scaling differences?

Comment: @George Take a look at the post linked in the original question.