# Characters have different weights depending on their race and sex. How does the weight (not Carry Weight/encumbrance) of a character affect the game?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are all the gender/racial perks?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39430/what-are-all-the-gender-racial-perks)

Characters (both player and NPC) may have different weights depending on their race and sex. See: http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Races

*Note that I am not referring to [Carry Weight AKA encumbrance](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Carry_Weight).*

All races and sexes have *1* weight, except for the male and female Altmer, male Argonian, and male Khajiit which all have *0.5* weight.

How does the weight of a character affect the game?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no difference I have tested all the races and they go the same speed. Same for damage, but are you including when you make your character and how you can make them different sizes. That would most likely be the same. Remember I'm saying this with the weight.

Comment: The different races will have different speeds because of their height. From http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Races: "*The movement speed of each race is dependent on its height. High Elves have the largest speed multiplier due to being the tallest race, with Orcs being second tallest.*"