# Does my character's customization affect game play?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have played over 100 hours of Skyrim. So far, I've only made two characters, a Nord woman and a male High Elf.

I know that race definitely affects stats, but does their gender or size affect anything *besides dialogue*?

There is a perk that changes the prices you get from a salesperson of the opposite gender, but I cannot think of anything else. I read somewhere that the size of mobs affects their power, so I was wondering if the same would apply to your avatar.

Also, does character appearance affect game play? I mean would attractiveness or certain facial features added, like facial hair, scars, etc. affect anything?

Comment: Appearance of what specifically? Your gender *definitely* affects your character's appearance

Comment: I don't think so. You are a blank slate. I don't think there are even specific spiecist events if you play a lizard, or a foul elf. Skyrim for the Nords!

And I think (not sure) you can also just marry any gender you want. (from the options) (yep: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/172127/are-same-sex-marriages-allowed )

So for a game that talks a lot about racism, and spiecism, there is not much of that you can actually experience first hand.

Comment: @Ids yeah that's why i assume the answer no, but i wanted to be sure :P

Comment: I can't recall any situations in which is was really relevant. But I have not finished all of Skyrim.

Comment: Related: [What are all the gender/racial perks?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/39430/4797)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Being a female doesn't directly give you more bonuses than being a
>   male (they get the same perks); however, there are more male
>   shopkeepers and enemies, so females tend to get more use out of perks
>   that affect the opposite gender. Speed is a function of height, so
>   being a female over a male will not increase speed. Other than that,
>   appearances have no direct impact on game play besides dialogue.

[source](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Character_Creation).